# How to disable time sync in Windows 7 Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, virtual-pc

I want to disable time sync between my Win 7 64bit host and Win XP SP3 virtual machine. The old tricks from Virtual PC 2007 does not seem to work anymore

```
<hardware>
  <bios>
   <time_sync_at_boot>
    <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
   </time_sync_at_boot>

 <integration>
  <microsoft>
   <host_time_sync>
    <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
    <frequency type="integer">15</frequency>
    <threshold type="integer">10</threshold>
   </host_time_sync>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By also adding the following line to the above changes seems to do the trick for me.

```
<hardware>
 <bios>
   <time_sync_at_boot type="boolean">false</time_sync_at_boot>
```